# Qt dial сравнить 2 числа предыдущее со следующим

Tags: c++, qt

мне необходимо сравнить 2 числа (a -следующее число, b- предыдущие). В переменной a записываю значение ползунка (dial). В переменной b приравниваю к а, чтобы он взял его значение, запомнил, чтобы потом сравнить. Проблема состоит в том, что они равны и если я перетаскиваю ползунок на другое число переменные a,b снова становятся равны, т.к. переменная b не запоминает предыдущее значение, а просто его дублирует. Как исправить ситуацию. Заранее благодарю.

```
void MainWindow::attempt5()
{
    int b=ui->dial->value();
    int a=b;
    if (a==b)
    {
        QString str=a+","+b;
        statusBar->showMessage(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void MainWindow::attempt5()
{
    int a=ui->dial->value();
    if (a==b)
    {
       Выполняем нужные действия
    }
    b = a; //глобальная переменная или поле класса
}
```